# Printing in Light Gray - what tint percentages work?

Tags: cmyk, grayscale

I have a publication with many light gray boxes (K-100%, tint 10%). I'm trying to design a Code style that will work both in the white-background normal text and in those shaded boxes.

We liked the idea of shading them and thought a 5% gray background looked good on screen. However, I'm a little worried the grays are too close. Is there a lower limit for a black tint going to a digital printer or the best difference for contrast?

Comment: How is this going to be printed? Fully digital, or offset litho (which is also digital these days)? Might be better to ask your print provider for a proof before going to print.  If it's litho - traditional CMYK printing, then tints will get half-toned, which doesn't look good with small text such as body text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the print is going to be digital, just make some tests, that is the advantage of modern digital prints.

I would prepare a series of squares starting with an empty one as a reference, with 5% increase values.

---

If you are doing it on traditional offset lithography, this could not be a good idea.

First, you need to define the text size, because screening at 10% using the same black ink as a text could make the text jaggy. So I would only do that on texts bigger than normal-reading-size text.

Depending on the quality of the printer and paper, but, in the old days, the range of percentages of a screened zone was from 5% to 95%. This is because lower or higher levels would have issues with some gaps being closed because of dot gain, and the lower values could be inconsistent.

One option is to use a spot ink, I would use it at 100% and probably at a lower percentage for your light version, let's say at 30-40%

---